# Is the complex cosine function surjective?

Tags: trigonometry, complex-numbers

Let $\cos z=\frac{e^{iz} - e^{-iz}}{2}$ be the complex cosine function.

Then is $\cos:\mathbb{C}\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ surjective?

If so, how do i prove this?

Comment: [In general](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picard_theorem)

Comment: Shouldn't be `+`?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/623775/proving-surjectivity-of-cosz-and-sinz-and-find-all-z-cosz-in-m

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Do it the usual way, take an arbitrary element $w\in \mathbb C$ and try to find $z$ such that $\dfrac{e^{iz} + e^{-iz}}{2}=w$. To do this transform this equation in a polynomial  of second degree on the variable $u$ with $u=e^{iz}$.